# create max quality Frame with FFMPEG from ProRes Clip

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, video-processing

I want to extract a frame from a ProRes Clip, recorded with a Blackmagic URSA Mini Pro 4.6K Gen 2 camera with ffmpeg.
I noticed the following: When I import the ProRes Clip into Davinci I can recover some highlights, which are out of the displayed range by lowering the gain paramater.
As you can see [in the waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKl9j.png) the thrid peak has information in all channels.

After I extracted the frame with ffmpeg, I couldn't recover the highlights anymore.
[Waveform: Values are clipped till the fifth peak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCo3u.png).

I used the following command:
`ffmpeg  -ss 00:00:01 -i 0volt.mov -vf zscale=t=input,zscale=c=input -frames:v 1  TIFFs\0volt.tiff -v verbose`

Here is the output of the ffmpeg command line: https://pastebin.com/a36ML3tL

Do you have any hint, how the original quality and dynanmic range by extracting a TIFF-Frame with ffmpeg can be retained?

Thank you!

Comment: Per the `ffmpeg` tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on [su] or [video.se].

Comment: I'm sorry. That was not clear to me, since there are many good answers to ffmpeg command line questions on stackoverflow. In the end it's a question about programming, because we want to use in a ffmpeg-python code. Our main goal is it to extract a full quality ProRes video frame in order to load into a numpy array. If there is a simpler solution than ffmpeg for that, it would be even nicer.